# How to fix InvalidPipeArgument error when iterate *ngFor from Observable Array of Objects

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an error when try to iterate *ngFor from Observable Array of Objects

I use Angular 8

Chat messages Service

```
private chatMessages = [];
private chatMessagesStream = new BehaviorSubject(this.chatMessages);

getMessages(): Observable<any> {
   return this.chatMessagesStream.asObservable();
}


addMessage(chatMessage) {
    this.chatMessages.push(chatMessage);
    this.chatMessagesStream.next(this.chatMessages);
}
```

Chat View Component

```
private chatMessages:Observable<Array<any>>;

constructor(
   private chatMessagesService: ChatMessagesService) {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chatMessagesService.getMessages().subscribe(messages => {
      this.chatMessages = messages;
      this.scrollMessagesToBottom(true);
    });
}
```

Chat HTML template

```
<div class="row conpeek_message_chat_row" *ngFor="let chatMessage of chatMessages | async ">
...
</div>
```

After init component i have an issue in console, what could be wrong ?

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove async pipe**

As `chatMessages` is **not observable**, its contains **pure value**.

```
this.chatMessagesService.getMessages().subscribe(messages => {
    this.chatMessages = messages; // <------- HERE , you are assigning value
    this.scrollMessagesToBottom(true);
});
```

---

**If you want to keep async pipe**, you have to assign `chatMessages` with `observable`, like this :

```
this.chatMessages = this.chatMessagesService.getMessages();
```

Comment: I want to keep async pipe, but when I try your second soultion, I get an error like ```ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: true'. Current value: 'ngIf: false'.```

Comment: @storin, please check you are using `this.chatMessages = this.chatMessagesService.getMessages();`

Comment: I edited an error desc, now is correct what I have in console. In Chat View Component i change this ```this.chatMessagesService.getMessages().subscribe(messages => {
    this.chatMessages = messages;
    this.scrollMessagesToBottom(true);
});``` to this ```this.chatMessages = this.chatMessagesService.getMessages();```

Comment: that's another error,it means your current issue is solved.its related to `*ngIf` please check that in your code. and also upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Ok, that could be true