# Why *ngFor make infinite loop when I use function to return value and crashing browser?

Tags: angular, loops, websocket, ngfor

I don't understand why *ngFor make infinite loop when I use function to return value.

I use Angular 8

**Chat View HTML Template**

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let chatMessage of chatMessages | async ">

   <div class="chat_message_inner [innerHTML]="getChatMessageText(chatMessage)"></div>

</div>
```

**Chat View Component**

```
private chatMessages:Observable<Array<any>>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.chatMessages = this.chatMessagesService.getMessages();
}

getChatMessageText(chatMessage) {
    if (chatMessage.type == 'text' || chatMessage.type == 'info') {
      console.log('TYPE TEXT');
      return chatMessage.value;
    }
    if (chatMessage.type == 'image') {
      let img_obj = `<div class="conpeek_msg_img_outer"><img src="${chatMessage.value}"></div>`;
      return img_obj;
    }
    if (chatMessage.type == 'file') {
      let file_obj = `<a>${chatMessage.filename}</a>`;
      return file_obj;
    }
  }
```

**Chat Messages Service**

```
private chatMessages = [];
private chatMessagesStream = new BehaviorSubject(this.chatMessages);

constructor(private dialogInfoService: DialogInfoService) {
    this.dialogInfoService.getDialogMembers().subscribe(members => {
      this.dialogMembers = members;
    });
}

getMessages(): Observable<any> {
   return this.chatMessagesStream.asObservable();
}

addMessage(chatMessage) {
    if (chatMessage.type != 'info') {
      for (let member of this.dialogMembers) {
        if (member.member_uuid == chatMessage.sender_dialog_uuid) {
          chatMessage.sender_name = member.member_presentation_name;
          chatMessage.avatar_id = member.avatar_id;

          if (member.member_uuid == this.dialogInfoService.getOwnDialogUUID()) {
            chatMessage.sender_type = 'contact';
            chatMessage.status = 'sending';
          } else {
            chatMessage.sender_type = 'consultant';
          }
        }
      }
    }

 this.chatMessages.push(chatMessage);
 this.chatMessagesStream.next(this.chatMessages);
}
```

After init this component and receive first message, I get infinite loop of messages `console.log('TYPE TEXT');` in console

When I use it to make request for an image message type to download a blob, my chrome browser is crashing.

Why is it happening, and how to fix it?

---

**EDITED**
I found the clue why I have "infinite" loop over here. I recreate the app with minimum additional code and all works almost good. But when I added WebSocket to my app, and when this webscoket make some action (open connection, send message, close connection etc.) my loop make iteration. The infinite loop is just a ping-pong messages which my websocket do with server to detect connections problems vert quickly.

Here I show the problem, check console logs after every action WS makes, or send ws msg by click the button.

I read something about it, and every change detection event like button click, http request or websocket action cause this loop iteration.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpb5hw

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to replicate your issue?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `chatMessageService`

Comment: @SachinGupta I edited the post and added this

Comment: @pkimtani I could be hard to do it now, but I try

Comment: <div class="conpeek_chat_message_inner [innerHTML]. You've missed out a quote mark after the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by putting `*ngFor` part of code to new component and add to this component decorator `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` option. 
On init have function to stop detect changes (`detach()`). Loop iterate now only when new messages from service comes (I added detachChanges in subcribe fn as below).

I need to isolate this component because in Angular every button click, request or WebSocket message trigers a Detection Change in whole application, now I controll this.

***ChatMessagesViewComponent***

```
@Component({
  selector: 'chat-messages-view',
  template: `... *ngFor html here only ...`,
  styleUrls: ['./chat-messages-view.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

constructor(private chatMessagesService: ChatMessagesService, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.chatMessages = this.chatMessagesService.getMessages();
  this.cd.detach();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.chatMessagesService.getMessages().subscribe(messages => {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.scrollMessagesToBottom(true);
  });
  this.scrollMessagesToBottom(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't closed the class quote

```
<div class="conpeek_chat_message_inner [innerHTML]="getChatMessageText(chatMessage)"></div>
```

2. Your chatMessagesService return an observable so you need to subscribe to it

```
 // this.chatMessages = this.chatMessagesService.getMessages();
    this.chatMessagesService.getMessages().subscribe(messages=>{
      this.chatMessages=messages
    })
```

3. As you have a behaviour subject with a default value you can safely subscribe before view has been initialised to avoid content checking errors. replace `ngAfterViewInit()` with `ngOnInit()`

I'm not sure how you were testing the `addMessage` function, but there's a chance that was accidentally within the observable itself which would cause the infinite loop.

As an extra point, once you receive the data from the service that would be a good time to populate the message text, instead of relying on function called from the html template.

Here's a minimal working reproduction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnrupp

Comment: 1. I have a good code, but when I paste it to the editor in StackOverflow i remove quote by accident.
2. But after that I can't user async pipe in ngfor in template, I have a antoher post about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57613718/how-to-fix-invalidpipeargument-error-when-iterate-ngfor-from-observable-array-o/57613744
3. I changed it to ngOnInit but it do not help.

I try to write totaly pure code from begeing witout additionas services, maybe it will help me to find the issuse. Now nothing helps.

Answer (score 0):

are you changing the value of `chatMessages` in `getChatMessageText(chatMessage)`. if so, it my be the source of this problem

Comment: ```getChatMessageText(chatMessage)``` is the same like I post, I think I do not change anything, I just return the right value

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your component:

```
chatMessageSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private chatMessageService: ChatMessagesService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.chatMessageSubscription = this.chatMessageService.chatMessagesStream .subscribe((messages: data) => {
            this.chatMessages = data;
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem still exist after you code unfortunately :/